# MultiLingual App Toolkit stopped working- Provider error always

Tags: visual-studio-2015, multilingual-app-toolkit

I have been using Multilingual App toolkit to translate resx files but recently it stopped working with the error message below. I thought that it is free and unlimited. Did I reach some certain limit? When I say Yes, nothing happens, no translation at all.

One other question, is it even possible to add a new provider like google translate? I thought that i watched on some presentation was saying it is possible but I couldn't figure it out how.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They moved to Azure Portal and it is paid service looks like now.

```
   Microsoft Translator is now available for purchase in the Azure portal.
 The Microsoft DataMarket platform retired on April 30, 2017.

    For Microsoft Translator API subscribers previously subscribed in Microsoft DataMarket,
 the move to the Azure portal requires a small code change in your applications.
```

https://cognitive.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1128340-announcements-action-required-before-april-30-20#signup

EDIT: Obviously single word translation is still supported for free but more than single word for a key doesnt work any longer.

Comment: The free tier has 2 million characters per month. Maybe you've used it all up? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/translator-text-api/

Comment: @Fai well, I havent connected to any azure account. my answer above is when you dont have  azure account logged in, it still translates a single word but more than 2 words or sentence doesnt work any longer

Comment: Above you say it's a paid service now. But there is a free tier in the Azure service, similar to what was true in the ADM service.

Comment: @Fai 2 million letters is pretty sufficient indeed for a small application, you can try and share your experience if it works fully as before. I have only dreamspark account for azure and it doesnt have any cognitive services unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

they moved indeed to azure. Have a look here: https://multilingualapptoolkit.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1167898-microsoft-translator-moves-to-the-azure-portal